# How to group and display chat messages by date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose

Im creating a chat application using Nodejs, MongoDB (Mongoose) and Angular 5. I want to know how i can split the chat messsages by date. So i can show which messages were sent on which date like how whatsapp does it.

**MongoDB - Schema.**

```
let MessageSchema = new Schema({

        chat_id: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Chat',
            required: true,
        },
        body: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        author: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User',
            required: true,
        },
        isRead: Boolean,
    },
    {
        timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'}
    });
```

**NodeJs - API Function /chat/:id to get the entire conversation**

```
show(req, res) {

        let id = req.params.id;

        Chat.findOne({_id: id})
            .populate('participants')
            .populate({
                path: 'messages',
                populate: {path: 'author'},
            })
            .exec((err, chat) => {

                if (err) {
                    return res.status(404).json({

                        success: false,
                        status: 400,
                        data: err,
                        message: 'Error retrieving user conversations',
                    });
                }

                return res.status(200).json({

                    success: true,
                    status: 200,
                    data: chat,
                    message: 'Successfully retrieve conversation',

                });

            });

    }
```

Angular - chat.component.ts

```
   getConversation() {

        this.route.params.switchMap((params) => {
            let conversation_id = params['id'];
            return this.conversationService.get(conversation_id);
        }).subscribe((res) => {
            this.conversation = res.data;
            this.getMessages(this.conversation._id); // Socket call
        });
    }


<ng-template ngFor let-message [ngForOf]="conversation?.messages" let-i="index">
```